# Ways to avoid using global variable while passing data to function fminbnd in Matlab

Tags: matlab, global-variables, nested-function

I have a very simple function in Matlab:

```
function [val] = rmsMin(z)
    Z1 = mainFig.UserData.Z1;
    Z2 = mainFig.UserData.Z2;
    val = rms(Z1 - Z2 + z);
end
```

I am trying to find the minimum value of this function running 1 variable optimization with function fminbnd:

```
[minZ, minRms] = fminbnd(@rmsMin, -5, 5);
```

My problem is: I cannot/(do not know how to) pass the data (Z1 and Z2) to the function rmsMin, so I have to use global variable mainFig which I am trying to avoid. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use auxiliary function handle that accept single input and call the main function with other supplement variables:

Script:

```
fun=@(z) rmsMin(z, mainFig.UserData.Z1,mainFig.UserData.Z2);
[minZ, minRms] = fminbnd(fun, -5, 5);
```

Main function:

```
function [val] = rmsMin(z,Z1,Z2)
    val = rms(Z1 - Z2 + z);
end
```